# Laravel 8 pass variable to be used in foreach loop for comparison

Tags: php, laravel, variables, foreach

I'm trying to pass a predefined variable with a value into the @if part of the statement for comparison. This is for Laravel v8.0 on the blade.php. It only works if I hardcoded the value in it but not through the variable $value. I would need to have a placeholder variable to pass the value for comparison, as it will be inputted from user. Hence may I know what is the proper way to declare the variable as in this case? Sorry I'm just starting learning Laravel. Thanks for your help.

Eg:

```
    $value = "abc123";

    @foreach($surveys as $survey)
        @if($survey->Unit_code == {{$value}})
            
            <form action="" method="">
                @csrf 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label> <br>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" value="{{$survey->name}}">
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Save">
            </form>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

Comment: just remove the ``{{}}`` around the value, as that's for putting a value into the dom, where the blade directive can handle the PHP variable already. If you need a PHP var to have a value and be set before the loop use the ``@php`` and ``@endphp``

Comment: this is what I refer to https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#raw-php this is how you allow raw PHP to be used in the dom with blade templates, if you want the data passed to the page separately then you need to return it on the backend as a second parameter to the ``view()`` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this is in an answer form for other users that encounter this problem as a developer just learning laravel; the issue here is there was an output to the dom using `{{}}` where the blade directives (things that start with `@`) use the PHP vars as is an example of this would be as follows:

```php
@if($survey->Unit_code == $value)
```

the other issue he was having, in this case, is assigning raw PHP on the blade file, this works the same way. Although, to add raw PHP to the dom you would use the `@php` directive

```php
    @php
        $value = "abc123";
    @endphp
    @foreach($surveys as $survey)
        @if($survey->Unit_code == $value)
            
            <form action="" method="">
                @csrf 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label> <br>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" value="{{$survey->name}}">
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Save">
            </form>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

if the data of `$value` needed to be completely dynamic based on the backend then I would recommend passing it to the blade file via the `view()` function instead and assigning the value there or as nullable on the first pass of the function. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks again for your helpful explanation. Yes, the intent is to later pull the value from the backend data table to the placeholder variable. I'll continue to work on it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use {{ }} in @if condition .

When you use @if(  ) everthing inside of it can translate into php .

So , you instead of using  :

```
 @if($survey->Unit_code == {{$value}})
```

Use :

```
 @if($survey->Unit_code == $value )
```

Hope that works .

Comment: It works now, thanks @saeed! It's strange that I remembered trying it among many things earlier but to no avail, and it now works well! Cheers.